# Increment the number by 1

Tags: c#

I would like to see label6 display the number of correct times the user chooses the number. And label7 display the number of times the user choose incorrectly. Its not incrementing by one.

Error 1 Operator '++' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string' 
Error 2 Operator '++' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string correct="0";
        string incorrect="0";
        RandomNumber(0,99);
        button2.Enabled = true ;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        label3.Visible = true;
        if (textBox1.Text == label1.Text)
            label3.Text=("Winner");
               label6.Text = correct +1;
               if (textBox1.Text != label1.Text)
                   label7.Text = incorrect= +1;
            label3.Text=(string.Format("Sorry - You Lose, The number is {0}",   label1.Text));

    }
```

**Edit** (From OP's answer to his own question):

I have tried the ways your suggesting but the number doesnt increase by one everytime I guess wrong.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


    {
        int correct=0;
        int incorrect=0;
        RandomNumber(0,99);
        button2.Enabled = true ;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        label3.Visible = true;
        if (textBox1.Text == label1.Text)
        {
            label3.Text = ("Winner");
            label6.Text = (++correct).ToString(); 
        }

        else if (textBox1.Text != label1.Text)
        {
            label7.Text = (incorrect+1).ToString(); 

            label3.Text = (string.Format("Sorry - You Lose, The number is {0}", label1.Text));
        }


    }
```

Comment: Or just `""+(int.Parse(correct)+1);`

Comment: Even if it works, Margus's suggestion is *The Wrong Way™*

Comment: yes this does compile. The problem is everytime I guess wrong on the number I want the label to display the amount of times I guess wrong. So if I guess wrong once that is 1 when I guess wron twice that is 2 and so on.

Comment: @Greg: I rolled back your change.  It fixes the OP's incorrect indenting, but I think the incorrect indenting is relevant to providing an answer to the OP's question.  Such fixes would be better posted as part of an answer to explain what is wrong with the OP's code.  Of course, that's all moot after the OP added a new chunk of code.  Fixing the spacing in **that** chunk of code seems less unreasonable...but also unnecessary :)

Comment: @randywhite30: The relevant issue (mentioned in gmcalab and Jeff M's answers), is that the two int variables should **not** be declared inside of the `button1_Click` function.

Comment: @randywhite30: Also, you are using `incorrect+1` instead of `incorrect++`, which will not increment incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to strings, `correct` and `incorrect` will just append the string representation of what's added.  You have to convert it to an integer type, then increment, then convert back to string.  However it would be easier to just keep these variables as integer instance variables.  That way incrementing is trivial and you are actually keeping the correct count and not resetting every time the button gets clicked.  (There are actually a number of problems with the code)

```
// instance variables
private int correct = 0;
private int incorrect = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RandomNumber(0,99);
    button2.Enabled = true ;
    button1.Enabled = false;
    label3.Visible = true;
    if (textBox1.Text == label1.Text)
    {
        label3.Text=("Winner");
        label6.Text = (++correct).ToString(); // convert int to string
    }
    // indentation does not indicate the block
    else //if (textBox1.Text != label1.Text)
    {
        label3.Text=(string.Format("Sorry - You Lose, The number is {0}",   label1.Text));
        label7.Text = (++incorrect).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't look like you're persisting the `correct` and `incorrect`

Create Properties:

```
public int Correct { get; set; }
public int Incorrect { get; set;}
```

Then:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RandomNumber(0,99);
   button2.Enabled = true ;
   button1.Enabled = false;
   label3.Visible = true;

   if (textBox1.Text == label1.Text)
   {
     label3.Text=("Winner");
     label6.Text = (++this.Correct).ToString();
   }
   else
   {  
      label3.Text=(string.Format("Sorry - You Lose, The number is {0}", label1.Text));
      label7.Text = (++this.Incorrect).ToString();
   } 
}
```

Comment: +1, but I really think you should have edited the indentation, too.

Comment: While *technically correct* (the best kind of correct ;-) ), I hesitate to upvote this due to indentation even though it mirrors the awfully-formatted original.

Comment: There I fixed indentation hopefully I didn't misunderstand his logic.

Comment: You don't need the condition for the `else`.  (If the code reaches the `else`, the boxes' contents are already unequal.)

Comment: @cHao - So `label7` and `label3` will magically set themselves, sorry, I disagree.

Comment: Well, you could get rid of the else by sticking a `return` statement at the end of the if block.  However, that would make the code less readable, in my opinion.  Yeah, this is the kind of question that leads to [bikeshed](http://bikeshed.com/) discussions.

Comment: Your answer evolved into mine.  :P

Comment: @Jeff : The last step in the evolution of this answer for the OP to tell us that he is using .Net 2.0.

Comment: @JeffM - woah! After I formatted that code I noticed a mistake or two and cleaned it up. I guess we were on the same track. :)

Comment: @gmcalab: I didn't say you didn't need the `else`.  I said you don't need the *condition*.  You know, the one you've since gotten rid of.

Answer (score 8):

You are storing your correct and incorrect variables as `string`.

Use `int` instead like this:

```
int correct = 0;
int incorrect = 0;
```

and change your code to:

```
correct++;
label6.Text = correct.ToString();
```

and:

```
incorrect++;
label7.Text = incorrect.ToString();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `label6.Text = correct.ToString()` and `label7.Text = incorrect.ToString();` instead? There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `string`.

Comment: Yes thanks, been a few years since I have done C#.  I fixed the example.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use:

correct = correct + 1; ( I think this is what you were trying to achieve)
incorrect = incorrect + 1;

OR

correct += 1;
incorect += 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
label6.Text = correct +1;
```

only sets label6's value to correct + 1; it does not change the value of correct. If you use:

```
int correct;
label6.Text = (++correct).ToString();
```

you should see what you want.

Comment: Yes, but since correct is a local variable, changing it is kind of pointless since it won't persist.

Comment: @Brian: that is correct; I should have been more clear and stated that the variable should be declared as an int as opposed to a string. Thanks for pointing that out.